# Socket communication failure

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I have a client which given me a non ssl url:port to send information(string containing xml data) to their server. I have used to Putty(in telnet mode) to successfully communicate with the server,and recieve the reply but when i am using the following code no communication is made

```
outputmsg = string.Empty;
                var m_socListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
                IPHostEntry ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("testurlhere");
                var ip = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress.AddressList[0], 10121);
                m_socListener.Connect(ip);

                byte[] tosend = GetBytes(inputmsg);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                m_socListener.Send(tosend); // doesnt sends data and returns immediately
                m_socListener.Receive(buffer); // waits forever
                m_socListener.Close();



 static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            return bytes;
        }

    static string GetString(byte[] bytes)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
        return new string(chars);
    }
```

Comment: Q: Are you absolutely sure "nothing is sent to the server"?  For example, maybe the server is waiting for "\n" (and you failed to send one in your "inputmsg").  There are many possible scenarios.  Definitely check for errors on the client; definitely check what - if anything - you're receiving on the server.  And definitely check for any firewalls between them.

Comment: yes, i have them checked the logs and found nothing hit the server.

Comment: If nothing is being sent to the server then maybe tosend does not have anything in it. If you are trying to get bytes from a string, use [Encoding.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes.aspx)

Comment: I'd use Wireshark to see what happens on the network level.

Comment: "testurlhere" - are you passing a hostname or an URL there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use right encoding in my case it is ASCII and append \n to the message as paulsm4 said.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution here might be to SetSockOpt NoDelay:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e160993d.aspx

I also second m0s's Most Excellent suggestion to try WireShark.  If you're not already familiar with it - satisfaction guaranteed!

But it sounds like NoDelay (disabling Nagle) might resolve the problem.  This link might help clarify:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm